# 30 days from first visit Javascript

Tags: javascript, web, cookies

I need to show a modal on my Webpage to the users after 30 days of the first visit.

I made a cookie which expires after 1 year of the first visit, I tried to subtract 335 days from the expiration date to have 30 days from creation date but it doesn't work.

Here's my cookie code

```
function GetCookie(name) {
  var arg=name+"=";
  var alen=arg.length;
  var clen=document.cookie.length;
  var i=0;
  while (i<clen) {
    var j=i+alen;
    if (document.cookie.substring(i,j)==arg)
      return "here";
    i=document.cookie.indexOf(" ",i)+1;
    if (i==0) break;
  }
  return null;
}
function testFirstCookie(){
    var visit=GetCookie("FirstTimeVisitCookie");
    if (visit==null){
      //it does something
   
   }
        var expire=new Date();
       expire=new Date(expire.getTime()+(1000 * 60 * 60 * 8760)); //expires in 1 year
       document.cookie="FirstTimeVisitCookie=here; expires="+expire + "; path=/";

       var month = new Date(expire.getTime() - (1000 * 60 * 60 * 8040)); // I substracted 335 days from expiration date to get 30 days from the creation of the cookie
        var time_now = new Date();
       time_now  = time_now.getTime();

        if (time_now >= month) {

            //shows a popup
         }
            
       
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    testFirstCookie();
});
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: A cookie won't work if the user subsequently uses a different browser. This requires a database driven solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First when you wanna compare 2 dates you should convert both of them to miliseconds.
In your code **time_now** is miliseconds but **month** is Date object that you should convert it to miliseconds by **getTime()** function.

Second You are setting allowed date to show the popup 30 days later and even if the code is completely correct indeed the if statement doesn't execute. because you should wait 30 days to the condition comes true or try with a fake date to test.

Third As @Dexygen said, A cookie won't work if the user subsequently uses a different browser. This requires a database driven solution.

```
var expire = new Date();
expire = new Date( expire.getTime() + (365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) ); //expires in 1 year
document.cookie="FirstTimeVisitCookie=here; expires="+expire + "; path=/";


var month = new Date(expire.getTime() - ( 335 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 ));  // I substracted 335 days from expiration date to get 30 days from the creation of the cookie
month = month.getTime()
var time_now = new Date();
time_now  = time_now.getTime();
var time_nowFake = new Date( time_now + (30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) ).getTime();

if (time_now >= month ) {

  console.log("doesn't work");
}

if (time_nowFake >= month) {
  console.log('yaaaaaay');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to add code to your backend server to detect a person viewing and then check if they have been there for a specific time after previous. However, you would need to use:

- IP tracking: **IPs can change**
- LocalStorage IDs: **If the browser is changed, this won't work.**
- Cookies: **They expire, and can mess up with different browsers**
- Redirect a user to have an ID in the URL: **Violates Google guidelines**

Comment: the website is actually made for seniors, they probably won't try to bypass the cookie